# How can I run Bokeh(version 0.13) server as backgroud service in linux?

Tags: python, linux, bokeh, daemon

Currently I am running bokeh server using this command in linux `bokeh serve DashboardDCD/ --port 5007 --allow-websocket-origin=52.171.38.120:5007` In this case i have to keep the terminal open. I want to run it in background as daemon. How can we do that? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep Linux Process running after exiting terminal, must we use disown command, it is used after the a process has been launched and put in the background, it’s work is to remove a shell job from the shell’s active list jobs.

In your case:

```
$ sudo bokeh serve DashboardDCD/ --port 5007 --allow-websocket-origin=52.172.38.117:5007 &
$ jobs
$ disown  -h  %1
$ jobs
```

The output should be something like this:

```
 $ sudo bokeh serve DashboardDCD/ --port 5007 --allow-websocket-origin=52.172.38.117:5007 &
 $ [1] Some ID number
 $ jobs
 $ [1] Running bokeh serve DashboardDCD/ --port 5007 --allow-websocket-origin=52.172.38.117:5007 &
 $ disown  -h  %1
 $ jobs
 $ [1] Running bokeh serve DashboardDCD/ --port 5007 --allow-websocket-origin=52.172.38.117:5007 &
```

Keep in mind this will make the process running in the background, but it wont make it restart if it crashes.

Comment: I tried this but, the moment i close the terminal i am not able to access it in browser.

Comment: @BhanudayBirla are you trying this locally or SSH, what is your machine's distribution?